# Can I add two wordpress shortcode plugins in the same site (not the same page)?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

Is there a problem with defining the same subdirectory structure for two or more WordPress plugins ? I have the following structure for my two plugins :

[subdir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA3Hx.png)

Then in a wordpress page I insert the first plugin and no problem.

But if I insert the second shortcode plugin in another page without the first one, and if I check the sources in the browser (CTRL + SHIFT + I) then I find the following subdirectories structure :

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccufh.png)
[source code in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccufh.png)

That is to say, WordPress mixed the subdirectories of the first plugin (which works perfectly in another page) with one subdirectory of the second plugin, and this last one is the one inserted at that page, not the first one...As a result, the javascript code is searching for images references that are not found because that subdirectory was not included.

If I deactivate de first plugin, then this page with the second plugin works correctly.

What is the problem ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOveflow! What's up with the external links? See how to ask on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or maybe ask on wordpress.org or wordpress.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It can be anything. It has nothing to do with wordpress. Having two plugins with the same directory structure is not a problem at all. It is how you include the images that causes the problem. So how exactly do you include them?

Comment: I dont understand the question about how I included the images...I simple include the subdirectories for images and javascript in its own subdirectories below the plugin subdirectory as can be seen in the images